# Image scraping and sending to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-scraping

I scraping some pages (I know, I know, I shouldn't, but the info from our intranet is not available in any other reliable way). So I inject a small `$(...).each(... $.ajax({}));` JavaScript and this works fine.

I got most info out of it, but now I need the images. I can get the URL, but I need to store them on the server (or on my local machine first). I can't use the URL because the images are behind username/password authentication.

Can I send them with a `$.ajax(multipart/form post - new FormData())` construct?

All idea's welcome.

Comment: Can't you just add an authorization header? See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax

Comment: @gd73 - adding the authorisation header is difficult, it uses expiring sessions, so that would be very difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the way to go, I tried, but got this error: "Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy". I tried the snippet on this webpage (just copy/paste into the console).

```
function getDataURL(srcImg, done) {
     var img = new Image();
     img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
     img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this,0,0);
        done(canvas.toDataURL());
    };
    img.src = srcImg.src;
}
getDataURL($("img")[0], function(data) { 
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: depends on the browser... so for my problem, it solved the issue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to encode them as base64 strings and store them that way.  Here's a fiddle demonstrating the method: http://jsfiddle.net/c8n9d4ce/

I also found [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/yvq5y/) that likewise demonstrates this method.

My code from the fiddle:

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var srcImg = document.getElementById("sourceImage");
    var final = document.getElementById("base64Image");

 var img = new Image();
 img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
 img.onload = function(){
  canvas.height = this.height;
  canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this,0,0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    canvas = null;
        final.src = dataURL;
 };
 img.src = srcImg.src;
```

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Original Image</h1>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/5YJ3HQ9.jpg" id="sourceImage">

<h1>Canvas Rendered Image</h1>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

<h1>Base64 Encoded Image</h1>
<img id="base64Image">
```

Comment: As below, under Safari you get the `Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy`, but it works fine under Firefox. Many thanks.

Comment: @Johan I'm sorry.  I haven't had any down time to hang out on SO lately.  Cross origin policy is a server setting that can be changed.  Some servers allow it while others do not.  If it's an in-house server, it can probably be changed.  If Firefox allows it anyway, then that works too; although, I don't know how it does.  Glad you got it to work though.